# Cloning remote git into local

Tags: git, version-control, clone, git-clone

I have a git repository on a remote server and am trying to clone it to a local folder. Here's what I've tried:

```
C:\Path\to\dir>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:\Path\to\dir\.git\

C:\Path\to\dir>git clone git://555.555.555.55/path/to/target/git/folder/
Cloning into 'folder'...
fatal: unable to connect to 555.555.555.55:
555.555.555.55[0: 555.555.555.55]: errno=No such file or directory
```

The directory path is mostly above the web root. How do I clone from that remote directory successfully?

Answer (score 0):

`555.555.555.55` is not a valid network address.

You need to find the correct path of your repository and call `git clone` on it.

Comment: Gee thanks :-) I replaced my IP address with a fake one for the question.

Comment: @itamar: from your error message it is clear that target machine is unreachable for some reason.

Comment: I believe it requires a username/password. I usually access it through FTP. Just don't know how to access the remote folders above webroot using ssh/git

Comment: Do you have a ``https`` or ``http`` access to the repository?

Comment: Usually SFTP. Isn't `http/https` only for below root level?

Comment: @itamar: Do you use public keys or username/password?

Comment: @itamar: try ``git clone git://username:password@555.555.555.55/path/to/target/git/folder/``

Comment: for some reason it keeps sticking the pw with the IP: `fatal: Unable to look up root (port password@555.555.555.55)`(the specified class was not found.)